# Tracepoint not working in gdb and it shows "Trace can only be run on remote targets"

Tags: gdb

I want to use tracepoints to debug a prog on a local machine where i have full access. I am able to set the tracepoint and its passcount and using info tr gives me

(gdb) info tr

Num Enb Address    PassC StepC What

1   y   0x080b7529 2     0     in search_tcp at tcp_pkt.c:412

Actions for tracepoint 1:
        collect flow
        end

Then i run the prog, it runs as usual and in the end when i give tfind or tdump to collect the required data it shows:

(gdb) tfind 1

Trace can only be run on remote targets.

(gdb) tdump

Trace can only be run on remote targets.

Even i tried using "tstart" but it shows again "Trace can only be run on remote targets."

Any idea on what is the meaning of this message ? Is tracepoing usage not supported currently ? OR is it for debugging some remote machine over LAN or some other network ? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks
vikas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Any idea on what is the meaning of this message ?

The meaning is *exactly* what the message says: the tracepoint facility is implemented *only* in `gdbserver`, and not in GDB itself, so you can't use `tstart` when debugging natively (when GDB controls the inferior (being debugged) process directly).

Instead, you need to set up a remote debugging session (which can still be done on a single machine):

```
gdbserver :10000 ./a.out  # start gdbserver listening on port 10000
```

In another window:

```
gdb -ex 'target remote :10000' ./a.out
```

Now you'll have GDB with a remote target (which is the `gdbserver` running on the same host), and `tstart` etc. will work.

Update:

> But now i see the following msg:
>   `(gdb) tstart`
>   `Target does not support this command.`
>   `(gdb) r`
>   `The "remote" target does not support "run".`

Before you can use `tstart`, you need to set trace and actions, as documented [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting-and-Stopping-Trace-Experiments.html).

And you can't `run` because the inferior process is *already* running. Use `continue` instead.

Update 2:

```
(gdb) trace testprog.c:273
Tracepoint 1 at 0x4578f7: file testprog.c, line 273.
(gdb) passcount 2 1
Setting tracepoint 1's passcount to 2
(gdb) actions 1
Enter actions for tracepoint 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
> collect id1
> end
(gdb) tstart
Target does not support this command
```

It sounds like your `gdbserver` is old, and does in fact *not* support tracing.

What do

```
gdb --version
gdbserver --version
```

produce?

Update 3:

Apparently your `gdbserver` **is** too old.

Even though GDB itself supported tracepoints since version 4.17, `gdbserver` only started supporting the tracepoints with version 7.2

Update 4:

> where to give this option "-f filename" that my program takes as input

Simple. You can read the [documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html) for gdbserver, but I believe you are looking for this invocation:

```
gdbserver :10000 ./a.out -f filename
```

Comment: hi...thanks a lot for the reply..i followed whatever you have written above ie running gdbserver in one terminal and running gdb cmd as written above in another terminal on the same host. Now i no longer get the message "Trace can only be run on remote targets". But now i see the following msg : (gdb) tstart
Target does not support this command.
(gdb) r
The "remote" target does not support "run".  Try "help target" or "continue".
My gdb version is also 7.0. Any idea what is the issue ? is it not supported on my gdb ? please let me know.

Comment: on one terminal i did:
gdbserver :10000 ./testprog
Process ./testprog created; pid = 31543
Listening on port 10000
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1

and on other terminal:
gdb -ex 'target remote :10000' ./testprog

(gdb) trace testprog.c:273
Tracepoint 1 at 0x4578f7: file testprog.c, line 273.
(gdb) passcount 2 1
Setting tracepoint 1's passcount to 2
(gdb) actions 1
Enter actions for tracepoint 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
> collect id1
> end
(gdb) tstart
Target does not support this command
please let me know the issue in this case.thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: $ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.0-ubuntu
$ gdbserver --version
GNU gdbserver (GDB) 7.0-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
gdbserver is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.This gdbserver was configured as "i486-linux-gnu"

Can you please let me know if version is the real issue ? Can there be some other reason ? If version is the issue, installing which version will solve the problem. 
Thanks a lot again for all the help. yours answers are very informative.

Comment: hi "Employed Russian", sorry to bother you again...can you please let me know the issue ? i think with all the help you gave, i may be very close to using tracepoints successfully. plz let me know. thanks...

Comment: Thanks "Employed Russian", i have installed 7.3 version now and it has solved this problem. But still i am facing one difficulty, my program takes a file as input. In usual debugging scenarios, i do 'gdb ./prog_name' and then 'r -f ./inputfile_name' and this works. Now i am not able to get how to give this option of my input file ie the '-f ./inputfile_name'. Also let me know which terminal (gdbserver or gdb) this option should be given. Thanks a lot again for all the help so far and your quick & timely replies.

Comment: hi "employed russian", can you please let me know where to give this option "-f filename" that my program takes as input. I hope that this will solve my problem and will be the last query in this thread. thanks a ton.

Comment: hi "employed russian", as per ur help i wrote a very small prog below to add two integers just to check the usage of tracepoints.

Comment: hi "employed russian" thanks for the help. now i am facing one related problem that i have elaborated at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329584/setting-the-tracepoints-but-not-able-to-find-the-trace-data-as-tfind-shows-targ" can you please let me know the solution. thanks a lot again.

Comment: @user1182722 If the answer worked for you, you are supposed to accept it.

Comment: sorry...i didn't know that, i am new to it...now i have accepted it...thanks for all your time and effort... :)

Comment: Why you supplied binary to client (gdb -ex 'target remote :10000' ./a.out) if it's connecting to server?