# setting the tracepoints but not able to find the trace data as tfind shows "Target failed to find requested trace frame."

Tags: gdb

i wrote a very small prog below to add two integers just to check the usage of tracepoints.

```
1 #include<stdio.h>
2 main(){
3         int x,y,sum;
4         x = 3;
5         y = 4;
6         sum = x + y;
7         printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
8 }
```

on one terminal, i ran gdbserver as :

```
$ gdbserver :10000 ./chk
Process ./chk created; 
pid = 13956
Listening on port 10000
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
```

On other terminal,i ran gdb as :

```
$ gdb -ex 'target remote :10000' ./chk
```

and then the following steps as shown below :

```
(gdb) trace chk.c:6
Tracepoint 1 at 0x80483fd: file chk.c, line 6.

(gdb) passcount 1 1
Setting tracepoint 1's passcount to 1

(gdb) actions 1
Enter actions for tracepoint 1, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".

>collect $regs
>end
(gdb) tstart
(gdb) tstatus
Trace is running on the target.
Collected 0 trace frames.
Trace buffer has 5242880 bytes of 5242880 bytes free (0% full).
Trace will stop if GDB disconnects.
Not looking at any trace frame.

(gdb) tstop
(gdb) tfind
Target failed to find requested trace frame.

(gdb) tdump
warning: No current trace frame.
```

Can anyone please let me know why tstatus,tfind and tdump are giving me such an output? What is the issue here? How can i check the value of my trace (which i have given here as $regs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why tstatus,tfind and tdump are giving me such an output

When you attach GDB, the inferior (being debugged) process is stopped in `_start` (i.e. has not reached `main` yet).

After you start the tracing experiment with `tstart`, you need to *continue* execution of the inferior, so it reaches your trace point, and automatically stops the trace (with `continue` GDB command).

Instead, you are stopping the experiment immediately (with `tstop`), which leads to empty trace.